# Why is the matrix equal to its transpose?

Tags: matrices, symmetric-matrices

[image]

In the lemma above I just clarify what the matrices below are.
[image]

The proof of this lemma is where I don't understand one thing, which I would like you to clarify:

Let $A = S + C$, where $s=1/2(A+A^T)$ and $c=1/2(A-A^T)$ . Then $x^tAx=x^TSx+x^TCx$. Now

$x^TCx=(x^TCx)^T=$ (<-- this is what I don't understand, why is it equal to its transpose?) $= x^TC^Tx= -x^TCx$. Therefore, $x^TCx=0$, thus gives the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because $x^T C x$ is a $1\times1$ matrix. Every such matrix is equal to its transpose

Comment: But why is $(x^TCx)^T=x^TC^Tx$? Isn't it supposed to equal $xC^Tx^T$?

Comment: @Marina you are not applying $(ABC)^T = C^T B^T A^T$ correctly